# How do you test to see if a double is equal to NaN?

Tags: java, double, equality, nan

I have a double in Java and I want to check if it is `NaN`.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 529, accepted):

Use the static [`Double.isNaN(double)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28double%29) method, or your `Double`'s [`.isNaN()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28%29) method.

```
// 1. static method
if (Double.isNaN(doubleValue)) {
    ...
}
// 2. object's method
if (doubleObject.isNaN()) {
    ...
}
```

Simply doing:

```
if (var == Double.NaN) {
    ...
}
```

is **not sufficient** due to how the [IEEE standard for NaN and floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is defined.

Comment: Another way to do this would be v != v. Only NaN compares false with itself. Don't do that though, isNaN is a million times better. :)

Comment: @Joren, better late than never: 'isNaN' is indeed better to use than v != v for readability. But the source code of the isNaN method is exactly the same as saying v != v.

Source: static public boolean isNaN(double v) {
    return (v != v);
}

Comment: ```Double.isNaN should be (true) ``` nice answer

Comment: @Joren isNaN just check v != v ;) but it looks better

Comment: Using Java 5: `value == Double.NaN` does not work, but `Double.isNaN(value)` works just fine.

Comment: @Rolf No. You would expect it, but it does not.  " d == Double.NaN" will never be true, even if d is NaN. You can NOT use it as a method for checking for NaN, you *have* to use isNaN

Comment: @Timo not sure what you want to say here. The source of `isNan` is equal to the statement `v != v` so what has `d == Double.NaN` to do with that?

Comment: @Rolf to be specific, I'm saying you're incorrect. Tell me, what is the result of  v != v ? - Note that v is the same variable

Comment: @Rolf No. You cannot use  " d == Double.NaN" - it will  never be true. Prove it to yourself with code, run this "System.out.println( "Value=" + (0.0/0.0) + " Comparison to Nan=" + ((0.0/0.0) == Double.NaN ) + " Comparison to Nan=" + Double.isNaN((0.0/0.0)));"
Result --> "Value=NaN Comparison to Nan=false Comparison to Nan=true".

Comment: @Rolf NaN is a valid VALUE of double (base type). IEEE insist (I imagine) that *any* comparison to the VALUE NaN must always be false, including to *itself*. 

What the NaN check does is compares the double to itself, and if it happens to return false then it must be a NaN because any other value would return true. compare(3,3)->true, compare(1,1)->true ... etc ... compare( Nan,Nan) --> false. It must be the only value that does that

So the OP *could* look for NaN by saying "if( myValue != myValue )" ... but it looks very weird and isNan is better, but == NaN will never work.

Comment: @Timo, First of all I never said `d == Double.NaN` will work. Secondly `v != v` works because: A. The Java Standard manual says so and B. The method `isNaN` uses this.

Comment: @Timo so I'm still uncertain what you're trying to correct here. We're basically saying the same, except for the `d == Double.NaN` part which I've never seen or said before.

Answer (score 52):

Try [`Double.isNaN()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28%29):

> Returns true if this Double value is a Not-a-Number (NaN), false otherwise.

Note that [`double.isNaN()`] will not work, because unboxed doubles do not have methods associated with them.

Comment: I thought you couldn't call methods on primitive types in Java. It really needs to be `Double.isNan()` and not `double.IsNan()`, right?

Comment: Joren, he's relying on autoboxing (double getting converted to Double by the compiler/runtime); new feature from 1.5 onwards. Little risk going this direction; going from Double to double creates risk of NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: I thought autoboxing only worked on using the double as an argument, adding it to a collection, and the like.  Try declaring double x and then asking x to isNaN() - gives me a compiler error.

Comment: Really, I suspect Andrew just missed the shift key typing the first "double".

Answer (score 22):

You might want to consider also checking if a value is finite via `Double.isFinite(value)`. Since Java 8 there is a new method in `Double` class where you can check at once if a value is not NaN and infinity.

```
/**
 * Returns {@code true} if the argument is a finite floating-point
 * value; returns {@code false} otherwise (for NaN and infinity
 * arguments).
 *
 * @param d the {@code double} value to be tested
 * @return {@code true} if the argument is a finite
 * floating-point value, {@code false} otherwise.
 * @since 1.8
 */
public static boolean isFinite(double d)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can check for NaN by using `var != var`. `NaN` does not equal `NaN`.

**EDIT**: This is probably by far the worst method. It's confusing, terrible for readability, and overall bad practice.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

I know, this way is very bad, and `isNan` is better for readability, but it works, right? And the `isNan` method uses this to check for `NaN`.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote was because this way is very bad, and isNaN is better for readability.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think additional comment would be useful here: if you compare wrappers like Float or Double you end up comparing references this way, not their values, which is definitely is not what you want.

Comment: @Battle_Slug Thanks for the comment. I do know that this is a very bad idea, but I put it here for completeness.

Comment: ```isNaN``` does this under the hood, but how does it work? How does something not equal itself ??

Comment: @wilmol custom class methods

Comment: method? You mean operator? ```!=``` operator is overloaded for ```Double``` class?

Answer (score 1):

If your value under test is a *Double* (not a primitive) and might be `null` (which is obviously not a number too), then you should use the following term:

`(value==null || Double.isNaN(value))`

Since `isNaN()` wants a primitive (rather than boxing any primitive double to a *Double*), passing a `null` value (which can't be unboxed to a *Double*) will result in an exception instead of the expected `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet will help evaluate primitive type holding NaN.

`double dbl = Double.NaN;
Double.valueOf(dbl).isNaN() ? true : false;`

Comment: There is never a need to write `condition? true: false`, as `condition` is already `true` when `true` and `false` when `false`. Even shorter is `Double.isNaN(dbl)` which skips the unnecessary conversion from a `double` value to a `Double` object.

Answer (score -3):

Beginners needs practical examples. so try the following code.

```
public class Not_a_Number {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String message = "0.0/0.0 is NaN.\nsimilarly Math.sqrt(-1) is NaN.";        
    String dottedLine = "------------------------------------------------";     

    Double numerator = -2.0;
    Double denominator = -2.0;      
    while (denominator <= 1) {
        Double x = numerator/denominator;           
        Double y = new Double (x);
        boolean z = y.isNaN();
        System.out.println("y =  " + y);
        System.out.println("z =  " + z);
        if (z == true){
            System.out.println(message);                
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Hi, everyone"); 
        }
        numerator = numerator + 1;
        denominator = denominator +1;
        System.out.println(dottedLine);         
    } // end of while

} // end of main

} // end of class
```

Comment: This example does too much, and it's not clear what you were trying to show. This is just a bunch of fragmented code.

Comment: As the OP, who was a beginner when this question was asked back in '09, I can assure you that the accepted answer was far more helpful than this "practical" example would have been.

Comment: Worse than providing a piece of code full of unnecessary things, this is a piece of code full of *discouraged* things.