# How to check if value is nan in unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert, nan

I've got functions, which sometimes return NaNs with `float('nan')` (I'm not using numpy).

How do I write a test for it, since

```
assertEqual(nan_value, float('nan'))
```

is just like `float('nan') == float('nan')` always false. Is there maybe something like `assertIsNan`? I could not find anything about it…

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you test to see if a double is equal to NaN in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456566/how-do-you-test-to-see-if-a-double-is-equal-to-nan-in-java)

Comment: It cannot be a possible duplicate if the language is different.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I came up with

```
assertTrue(math.isnan(nan_value))
```

Answer (score 13):

`math.isnan(x)` will raise a `TypeError` if `x` is neither a `float` nor a `Real`.

It's better to use something like this :

```
import math


class NumericAssertions:
    """
    This class is following the UnitTest naming conventions.
    It is meant to be used along with unittest.TestCase like so :
    class MyTest(unittest.TestCase, NumericAssertions):
        ...
    It needs python >= 2.6
    """

    def assertIsNaN(self, value, msg=None):
        """
        Fail if provided value is not NaN
        """
        standardMsg = "%s is not NaN" % str(value)
        try:
            if not math.isnan(value):
                self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))
        except:
            self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))

    def assertIsNotNaN(self, value, msg=None):
        """
        Fail if provided value is NaN
        """
        standardMsg = "Provided value is NaN"
        try:
            if math.isnan(value):
                self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))
        except:
            pass
```

You can then use `self.assertIsNaN()` and `self.assertIsNotNaN()`.

Comment: Nice. You can achieve the same without importing the math module by simply using the comparison `value != value` which evaluates to True for nan values.

Comment: @Richard That is very dangerous and not at all to the point of the question. Context: `float("NaN") != float("NaN")` would evaluate to `True`, but so would `float("NaN") != 3`, which is not at all what the user is trying to do (assert if the value _is_ nan).

Comment: @SlobodanIlic I think you misunderstood my comment. Provided you have the variable `a = 3`, then you would not write `float('nan') != a` to check if its value is nan. You would write `is_nan = (a != a)`. That way `is_nan` is only True, if a is indeed nan.

Comment: @Richard You are correct, I did misunderstand. Thanks for clarifying. I'm gonna leave the original comment in place for consistency.

Answer (score 5):

**Update with NumPy:** I know the OP is not using `numpy`. However, I had to use `numpy` and didn't find any post. So I'll leave the answer here for anybody that may need help. It also works perfectly with `unittest` library.

```
import numpy as np
np.testing.assert_equal(nan_value, np.nan)
```

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a corresponding `np.testing.assert_not_equal()` for testing non-equality to `np.NaN`:(. But `assertFalse(math.isnan(nan_value))` works.

Answer (score 1):

Keying off of @user3503711's answer, the following worked for me:

```
numpy.isnan(nan_value)
```

I am using numpy==1.22.2. See https://numpy.org/doc/1.22/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html