# unittest - how to assert if the two possibly NaN values are equal

Tags: python, nan, equality, python-unittest

In my test case, I assume that if two values are `NaN` then they are equal. What is the way to express it using `unittest` assertions? The two common functions presented below are not handling this case.

```
v1 = np.nan
v2 = np.nan
self.assertEquals(v1, v2)
self.assertTrue(v1 == v2)
```

A solution that is working for me right now is using a boolean expression inside `assertTrue`:

```
self.assertTrue(v1 == v2 or (np.isnan(v1) and np.isnan(v2))
```

Comment: I'd probably write my own assertion method, e.g. `assertBothNan`, or override `assertEquals` if you always want that behaviour. As to how you check if a value is NaN: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16890902/3001761

Comment: This will not work, `v1==v2` will be False. You should check that both are Nan separately and then write your own assertion method.

Comment: That's why I am looking for a solution covering a case when both values are not NaN and when they are both NaN. I will understand if there is only a complex boolean expression available at the moment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use:

```
numpy.testing.assert_equal(v1, v2)
```

From [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_equal.html):

> This function handles NaN comparisons as if NaN was a “normal” number.
>   That is, no assertion is raised if both objects have NaNs in the same
>   positions. This is in contrast to the IEEE standard on NaNs, which
>   says that NaN compared to anything must return False.

It throws AssertionError when the values are not equal and it should work fine with pytest, but it may not be a good fit for unittest tests.

Another option is:

```
numpy.isclose(v1, v2, equal_nan=True)
```

but obviously it's a replacement for `math.isclose`, not for `==`.

Comment: note that this does not work for 'object' dtypes: e.g. `np.array(["hello",np.nan],dtype='object')` raises an error

Answer (score 5):

It does not make sense to check two NaNs for equality. The best you could do is to check it in a different way, for example:

```
check = numpy.isnan(v1) and numpy.isnan(v2)
self.assertTrue(check)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [math.isnan](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan)

```
self.assertTrue(math.isnan(v1) and math.isnan(v2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if each of them is NaN separately. To do that, I suggest using the following class:

```
import math


class NumericAssertions:
    """
    This class is following the UnitTest naming conventions.
    It is meant to be used along with unittest.TestCase like so :
    class MyTest(unittest.TestCase, NumericAssertions):
        ...
    It needs python >= 2.6
    """

    def assertIsNaN(self, value, msg=None):
        """Fail if provided value is not NaN"""
        standardMsg = "%s is not NaN" % str(value)
        try:
            if not math.isnan(value):
                self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))
        except:
            self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))

    def assertIsNotNaN(self, value, msg=None):
        """Fail if provided value is NaN"""
        standardMsg = "Provided value is NaN"
        try:
            if math.isnan(value):
                self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))
        except:
            pass
```

It would be as easy as:

```
v1 = np.nan
v2 = np.nan
self.assertIsNaN(v1)
self.assertIsNaN(v2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A standard way of checking for `nan`s is

```
assert (v1 != v1) and (v2 != v2)
```

i.e. something that is not equal to itself, e.g:

```
>>> n = float('nan')
>>> n != n
True
```