# unittest check for Nan

Tags: python, nan, python-unittest

I am facing the problem of checking if my function returns nan in one of the unittest cases.

Doing a bit of research I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890902/how-to-check-if-value-is-nan-in-unittest) which already asks how to do it and a solution is provided.

One of the solutions is using `assertTrue(math.isnan(nan_value))` but it has the downside of raising a `TypeError` if `x` is neither a `float` nor a `Real`.

The other solution consist on defining a class of Numerical Assertions where you can handle the nan case. I could implement this and happily solve my problem.

However checking for nan looks like a common test that a lot of people might need to do (either in unittests or just in plain if/else blocks).

So my question is a bit like: Is there already a implementation that does this in a stardard way, so anybody that checks for nans will always run the same code and obtain the same result? Or the common approach is to define myself the check provided in the linked question?

Does a feature like this exist in numpy, math or unittest libraries? I think it would be extremely useful to have an `assertNan` function in unittest

Answer (score 2):

Given that for non-`float` data type it is not nan either way I would use the implicit feature of the order of evaluation (and skipping) for `and` logical clauses. Namely, if the first operand is `False`, then the second part is not evaluated:

```
assertTrue(type(nan_value) is float and math.isnan(nan_value))
```

In the code above if the type of `nan_value` is not `float` then the `and` clause is `False` so `math.isnan(nan_value)` is not evaluated and no `TypeError` is generated.