# ( Java) When I enter a non-number (NaN) my program loops infinitely where is supposed to exit.

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop, exit, nan

The code is supposed to keep accepting numbers >-10 for as long as you enter them. Then when you are ready to exit you just enter anything other than a number and it is supposed to take the mean value of the sum of the numbers recorded and print the value, then exit.

When I enter a non-number (NaN) my program loops infinitely and I can't figure out how I can keep this from happening.

Program so far:

```
package project1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class mean 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
System.out.println("Enter the Temperature: ");  

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

double value=0.0;
double sum=0;
int i=0;

//This infinitely loops when a non Double value is entered. WHY!?!?!?
while(value != Double.NaN) {
    value = averageTemperature(input, -10);
       sum += value;                           
        i++; 
        System.out.println("I've been here " + i + " time(s)");
       if (value == Double.NaN){
           break;
       }
 }                  


double mean = sum / i;                          

System.out.println("The average temperature is: " + mean);
}




public static double averageTemperature(Scanner input, double lowestTemp)
{
double temp = 0.0;

    if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
    temp = input.nextDouble();

        if(temp >= lowestTemp){                              
        return temp;
        }                         
        else if (temp < lowestTemp)                      
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid temperature. Please Re-enter: ");
            return averageTemperature(input,lowestTemp);   
        } 
    }
    return Double.NaN;  

}
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456566/how-do-you-test-to-see-if-a-double-is-equal-to-nan-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false

Answer (score 3):

By definition, [`NaN` is not equal to anything, including itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values). Thus

```
while(value != Double.NaN) {
```

doesn't work as you'd expect. Use [`Double.isNaN()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) instead.

> When I enter a non-number (NaN)...

Just to be clear with the terminology, "a non-number" and not-a-number are not the same thing:

- a non-number can be pretty much anything, e.g. an alphanumeric string;
- a not-a-number ([NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)) is a specific [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floating-point value.