# How to "declare" NaN for a if statement?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, nan

I have a code for a quadratic formula solver, but I can't get NaN to behave with my `if` statements.

```
package homework;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
//                          My Name 9/18/18 
// The purpose of this class is to allow a user to input an a,b, and c     value     and perform the quadratic equation on them
public class QuadFormHW 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double a,b,c,answer1,answer2;
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter an \"a\" \"b\" and \"c\" value.");
    a = inputReader.nextDouble();
    b = inputReader.nextDouble();
    c = inputReader.nextDouble();
    answer1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
    answer2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
    if (answer1 == NaN)
    {
        System.out.print("Error cannot calculate");
    }
    else if (answer2 == NaN)
    {
        System.out.print("Error cannot calculate");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.printf("Your answers are: %.3f , %.3f",answer1,answer2); 
    }
    inputReader.close();
}
```

}

Can anyone help me understand why `NaN` isn't a acceptable value?

Comment: Use Float.NaN instead?

Comment: In this very specific case you can check for all places where a NaN would occur without ever performing the calculation: `Math.sqrt(x)` is NaN if `x < 0` and `x/y` is NaN if `y` is 0.

Before you calculate do: `double toCheck = Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c); if(toCheck < 0 || a == 0) { /* would be NaN */ }` and only calculate the rest if neither of these would cause a NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking the same question as this older QA posting: [How do you test to see if a double is equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456566/how-do-you-test-to-see-if-a-double-is-equal-to-nan) (I've marked this as a duplicate of that).

In short: **By design**, `NaN` cannot be meaningfully compared to any other value, (so `foo == NaN` won't work for your purposes). This is because of NaN-propagation.

Instead, to test for `NaN`, use `Double.isNaN( value )` or `Float.isNaN( value )`.

Comment: Why did you post an answer summarizing another answer, especially if you voted to close as duplicate?

Comment: Thanks so much this fixed my problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The accepted answer to the linked question had an error in it lol. At least this one was correct from the start.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I wanted to provide a helpful answer to the OP before the question was closed as a duplicate, in case the OP didn't see the Dupe link.

Comment: Makes sense, especially given Pluto's comment