# How to prevent NaN values appending to ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have data stored in DoubleTimeSeries as:

```
DoubleTimeSeries width = DoubleTimeSeries.getDoubleTimeSeries(connection, userId, "Width");
DoubleTimeSeries height = DoubleTimeSeries.getDoubleTimeSeries(connection, userId, "Height");
```

and I am adding the above results into ArrayList as:

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < width.size(); i++) {
    myArray.add(width.get(i) + "," + height.get(i) );
}
System.out.println("My Array: \n" + myArray);
```

**My issue**: Some of the width or height value is empty (it is NaN) in my file and when i am adding them into my ArrayList, I am getting such as:

```
[NaN,NaN, 25,50, 55, 60, NaN,NaN, 45,56]
```

Now: How I can prevent (or ignore) these NaN values from adding into my ArrayList. I want the ArrayList results as:

```
[25,50, 55, 60, 45,56]
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you test to see if a double is equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456566/how-do-you-test-to-see-if-a-double-is-equal-to-nan)

Comment: @cutiko Thanks for your comment. I already tried this, I wrote the if statement inside my for loop but did not work.

Comment: just add a test for the width : 
if (width.get(i)==NaN){i++} and do not use `for` use `do .. while`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the value with NaN, and only add if false.

```
for (int i = 0; i < width.size(); i++) {
    if (!Double.isNaN(width.get(i)) && !Double.isNaN(height.get(i))) {
        myArray.add(width.get(i) + "," + height.get(i) );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. Is there any include for this? I am getting ``cannot find symbol method isNan(double)``.

Comment: @Bilgin It's `isNaN` not `isNan`

Comment: @VladislavKryshtanovskiy Approved.

Answer (score 1):

just add a test for the width : if (width.get(i)==NaN){i++} and do not use `for` use `do .. while`