# Print INFINITY values to something else in JAVA

Tags: java

I am having calculation in my java coding, my problem now is whenever i hit 0 divide by 0, it prints the value `?`.
My question is, can i change the `?` to print `0` or something else? Is that possible?
Below is my code,

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("0.00");
if (rowset[9] == null) {rowset[9]="0";out.print("0.00");} 
else out.print(df.format(Double.valueOf(rowset[9])/Double.valueOf(rowset[10])));
```

Comment: You're probably printing NAN ("Not A Number").  0/0 is not 0, so you shouldn't print that.  What else would you like to print?  How about "NAN"?

Comment: @markspace yeah i guess it is NAN behind the "?" that is currently printing now, Yeah, i can print anything, other than the `?` i am getting now

Comment: Google also suggests "undefined" for 0/0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like (not tested):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("0.00");
if (rowset[9] == null) {rowset[9]="0";out.print("0.00");} 
else {
  double result = rowset[9] / rowset[10];
  if( result != result )
     System.out.println( "undefined" );
  else
     out.print( df.format( result ) );
}
```

After writing this, I did a search and found a better way to test for NAN.  I guess I should RTFM.  [How do you test to see if a double is equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456566/how-do-you-test-to-see-if-a-double-is-equal-to-nan)

Comment: Thanks mate, this solved my problem! I guess i should read the manual also.